# A simple C WinAPI program for terminating processes via process image names - follow-up 3

Tags: c, windows

(See the next follow-up [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/262793/a-simple-c-winapi-program-for-terminating-processes-via-process-image-names-fo).)

This is the 4th version of the program killer tool:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")

static const char* get_last_err_msg() {
    DWORD errorMessageId = GetLastError();

    if (errorMessageId == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    LPSTR messageBuffer = NULL;
    size_t size =
        FormatMessageA(
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | 
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, 
            NULL, 
            errorMessageId, 
            MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), 
            (LPSTR)& messageBuffer,
            0,
            NULL);

    char* errmsg = _strdup(messageBuffer);
    LocalFree(messageBuffer);
    return errmsg;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        char* bname = _strdup(argv[0]);
        PathStripPath(bname);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s PROCESS_NAME\n", bname);
        free(bname);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

    if (snapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "Error: could not get the process snapshot. "
            "Cause: %s\n", get_last_err_msg());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    size_t totalProcesses = 0;
    size_t totalProcessesMatched = 0;
    size_t totalProcessesTerminated = 0;

    if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry)) {
        do {
            totalProcesses++;

            if (strcmp(entry.szExeFile, argv[1]) == 0) {
                totalProcessesMatched++;

                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, 
                                              FALSE, 
                                              entry.th32ProcessID);

                if (hProcess == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr,
                            "Error: could not open the process with ID = %d, "
                            "called \"%s\". "
                            "Cause: %s", 
                            entry.th32ProcessID, 
                            entry.szExeFile,
                            get_last_err_msg());
                } else {
                    if (TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0)) {
                        totalProcessesTerminated++;
                        printf("Terminated process ID %d\n", 
                                entry.th32ParentProcessID);
                    } else {
                        fprintf(
                            stderr, 
                            "Warning: could not terminate the process with ID %d. "
                            "Cause: %s",
                            entry.th32ProcessID,
                            get_last_err_msg());
                    }

                    if (!CloseHandle(hProcess)) {
                        fprintf(
                            stderr,
                            "Warning: could not close the handle to the process ID %d. "
                            "Cause: %s",
                            entry.th32ProcessID,
                            get_last_err_msg());
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry));
    }

    BOOL snapshotHandleClosed = CloseHandle(snapshot);

    if (!snapshotHandleClosed) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "Warning: could not close the process snapshot. Cause: %s",
                get_last_err_msg());
    }

    printf("Info: total processes: %zu, "
           "total matching processes: %zu, total terminated: %zu.\n", 
           totalProcesses,
           totalProcessesMatched, 
           totalProcessesTerminated);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

***Critique request***

Is there anything else I could do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Memory ownership

This:

```
char* errmsg = _strdup(messageBuffer);
LocalFree(messageBuffer);
return errmsg;
```

is problematic. The documentation for `_strdup` says that

> The `_strdup` function calls `malloc` to allocate storage space for a copy of `strSource` and then copies `strSource` to the allocated space.

So you're allocating, reallocating, doing one free, and leaving the second buffer dangling. The typical solutions for this are

- Make the caller contract such that the caller is responsible for calling `LocalFree`, and don't call `strdup` at all. If you do this, the `""` case must use your own `malloc` and `strcpy`.
- Have `get_last_err_msg()` accept a buffer and size instead, and simply have `FormatMessage` fill that buffer
- Accept a callback function pointer that is called with the message, after which `get_last_err_msg()` does the free - this one is needlessly complicated for this application

I recommend the second.

### Logic inversion

Change this:

```
        if (strcmp(entry.szExeFile, argv[1]) == 0) {
```

to

```
        if (strcmp(entry.szExeFile, argv[1]) != 0)
            continue;
```

so that the rest of the loop can be de-indented.

Comment: I don't agree about adding `continue`, the need to do that always originates from cluttered, needlessly complex loops. In this case the solution is to split the big function into several. The OpenProcess + handling the results from it looks like a good candidate for a separate function.